# How to control TemplateField order

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I have a grid view where the columns is generated dynamically through the code `[AutoGenerateColumns="false"]` with one `TemplateField` but also I am creating another `TemplateField` from ASPX

How can I control the order of these two `TemplateField` 
For example, I need the `TemplateField` that generated from code first and then `TemplateField` the generated from ASPX is second as new row in the gridview.

```
TemplateField templateField = new TemplateField();
TemplateField uid = new TemplateField();
uid.HeaderText = "userid";
uid.ItemTemplate = new AddItemTemplate(ListItemType.Item, "userid");
GridView1.Columns.Add(uid);
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
   BoundField boundField = new BoundField();
   if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString() != "userid")
   {
      boundField.DataField = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
      boundField.HeaderText = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
      GridView1.Columns.Add(boundField);
   }
}
```

aspx code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div<%# Eval("userid") %>" >
                                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" AllowSorting="true" >
                                    <Columns>
                                        --code--
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Is there any way to control this?

Comment: i thought the order of template feild starts from the aspx code. Dynamically generated template fields index starts after assigning index to the template field in aspx code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
GridView1.Columns.Add(boundField);
```

Use:

```
GridView1.Columns.Insert(0, boundField);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfieldcollection.insert.aspx